# Append a portion of a string to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how one can append a portion of a string to a list? Is there an option of both appending based on the position of characters in the string, and another option that is able to take a specific character of interest? For instance, If I had the string "2 aikjhakihaiyhgikjewh", could I not only append the part of the string that was in positions 3-4 but also append the "2" as well? I'm a  beginner, so I'm still kinda new to this python thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) to accomplish what you are looking for:

```
mystr = "2 aikjhakihaiyhgikjewh"
lst = list(list([item for item in [mystr[0] + mystr[3:5]]])[0])
print lst
```

This runs as:

```
>>> mystr = "2 aikjhakihaiyhgikjewh"
>>> lst = list(list([item for item in [mystr[0] + mystr[3:5]]])[0])
>>> print lst
['2', 'i', 'k']
>>>
```

Slicing works by taking certain parts of an object:

```
>>> mystr
'2 aikjhakihaiyhgikjewh'
>>> mystr[0]
'2'
>>> mystr[-1]
'h'
>>> mystr[::-1]
'hwejkighyiahikahjkia 2'
>>> mystr[:-5]
'2 aikjhakihaiyhgi'
>>>
```

Comment: could you explain the notation on your second block of code, please? Specifically when you are defining lst

Answer (score 2):

You can use slicing to reference a portion of a string like this:

```
>>> s = 'hello world'
>>> s[2:5]
'llo'
```

You can append to a list using the `append` method:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l.append('Potato')
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'Potato']
```

Best way to learn this things in python is to open an interactive shell and start typing commands on it. I suggest [ipython](http://ipython.org/) as it provides autocomplete which is great for exploring objects methods and properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can append a portion of a string to a list by using the .append function.

```
List = []
List.append("text")
```

To append several parts of the string you can do the following:

```
List = []
String = "2 asdasdasd"
List.append(String[0:2] + String[3:5])
```

This would add both sections of the string that you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing 2 separate operations: [slicing a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation), and [extending a list](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html#d0e5887). Here is how you can put the two together:

```
In [26]: text = "2 aikjhakihaiyhgikjewh"

In [27]: text[0], text[3:5]
Out[27]: ('2', 'ik')

In [28]: result = []

In [29]: result.extend((text[0], text[3:5]))

In [30]: result
Out[30]: ['2', 'ik']
```